# Get spring.profiles.active in Tiles.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles, tiles2, apache-tiles

Can we recover the active profile in tiles.xml?

I need to display an indicator in the title of the active profile.

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>QA</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Tiles.xml**

```
<definition name="base.layout" template="/WEB-INF/views/layout/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="My title - GET PROFILE ACTIVE HERE" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/layout/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="contentLayout" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/layout/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use app.properties as follows?

```
spring.profiles.active=QA
```

then in your xml you can use:

```
<util:properties id="app.properties" location="classpath:application.properties"/>

<definition name="base.layout" template="/WEB-INF/views/layout/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="${spring.profiles.active}"/>
 ...
</definition>
```